# Get sum of an array in 3 ways, for, while and recursive

Tags: array, comparative-review, reinventing-the-wheel, raku

So i was trying to find sum of an array using 3 ways in perl6

- for
- while
- recursive

(I know there are inbuilt perl6 functions for this)

I want to know if there is a better way to do this or is this it?

```
sub sumFor(@list)
{
   my $sum = 0;
   for (@list)
   {
      $sum += $_;
   }
   return $sum;
}


sub sumWhile(@list)
{
   my $sum = 0;
   my $index = 0;
   while ($index < @list.elems)
   {
      $sum += @list[$index++];
   }
   return $sum;
}

sub sumRec(@list, $index = 0)
{
   my $sum = 0;
   if ($index < @list.elems)
   {
      $sum = @list[$index] + sumRec(@list,$index+1);
   }
   return $sum;
}

my @list = 1,2,3,4;

say sumFor(@list);
say sumWhile(@list);
say sumRec(@list);
```

Comment: And do you have any particular concerns about these 3 versions to be reviewed?

Comment: _"I want to know if there is a better way to do this or is this it?"_ Do you want to know which is the best out of these 3 ways, or getting a completely different solution? Your question is still unclear for me.

Comment: These are programs written for learning, i don't want a comparison between functions or performance review, rather a general review which looks into usage of language features

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may already know the following Perl 6 tidbits, but for others reading along:

- The ordinary **OO** way to express the sum of a list of numbers in a variable `list` is `list.sum`;
- The ordinary **functional** way to express the same thing is `sum list`;
- A less common functional idiom that produces the same result is `[+] list` which is a [reduction](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#Reduction_Operators).

Imo your code is fine. That said:

## Parentheses are frequently optional

Larry often pipes up about what he calls "superstitious parens". More generally I think there's a rough consensus among Perl 6 folk that readability for most folk is best served by *omitting* optional parentheses when the meaning remains clear without them. This is almost always true around conditional expressions. I generally omit them around argument lists too. If I were writing the code you've written I'd likely have dropped seven pairs of "superstitious parens" thus:

```
sub sumFor(@list)
{
   my $sum = 0;
   for @list
   {
      $sum += $_;
   }
   return $sum;
}

sub sumWhile(@list)
{
   my $sum = 0;
   my $index = 0;
   while $index < @list.elems
   {
      $sum += @list[$index++];
   }
   return $sum;
}

sub sumRec(@list, $index = 0)
{
   my $sum = 0;
   if $index < @list.elems
   {
      $sum = @list[$index] + sumRec @list,$index+1;
   }
   return $sum;
}

my @list = 1,2,3,4;

say sumFor @list;
say sumWhile @list;
say sumRec @list;
```

## Sigils are frequently optional

I don't know of any emerging consensus about use of sigil'd variables vs [non-sigil'd variables](https://docs.perl6.org/language/variables#Sigilless_variables) but you can slash sigils like this:

```
sub sumRec(\list, \index = 0)
{
   my $sum = 0;
   if index < list.elems
   {
      $sum = list[index] + sumRec(list,index+1);
   }
   return $sum;
}
```

## Stronger typing

Most built in operations accept arguments of a wide range of types and automatically coerce them to fit the operation. This highly generic approach is considered a strength. Thus, for example:

```
say sum '21', '21'; # 42
```

This genericity is the default in Perl 6 code. But sometimes you may prefer to explicitly specify types. Thus, perhaps:

```
subset NumericList of List where .all ~~ Numeric;

sub sumFor(NumericList \list )
{
   my $sum = 0;
   for list
   {
      $sum += $_;
   }
   return $sum;
}

my \list = 1,2,3,4,'a';
say sumFor list; # "Constraint type check failed..."
```